# How to disable and enable css rule

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example if i have

```
<style type='text/css' id='divcolorgreen'>
    div{
        color: green;
    }
</style>
```

I can disable the css rule using 3 ways

- removing the style element (reappend it to reenable)
- modifying it's inner html
- add the inline rule one by one to each elements (better using jquery)

Is there any easier way to disable/remove the css rule?

Comment: i found the easiest way already. it's totally different to the accepted answer i tick below. i hope u all find it out soon

Comment: What did you use finally? After all, you could add your own answer, or mention it in the comments. This site is aimed at providing help to other users, so sharing your knowledge is definitely desired :) Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the purpose of classes. By assigning a class eg. to the `<body>` tag, you get the same functionality:

```
<style type='text/css' id='divcolorgreen'>
    body.divcolorgreen div{
        color: green;
    }
</style>
```

And then if `<body>` looks like this:

```
<body class="divcolorgreen">
    ...
</body>
```

the rule is applied. To disable the rule, remove the mentioned class:

```
<body>
    ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you are trying to change the color of all divs on a page.

jQuery has `.css()` which lets you set the style of all elements that match the selector. In your case, it's just `div`.

To set:

```
$('div').css('color', 'yellow');
```

To remove:

```
$('div').css('color', '');
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, the idea is the same:

`document.getElementsByTagName('div')` gives you all divs on the page. You can loop through them and change their style by `elem.style.color="yellow";`

Answer (score 1):

1 you can do this by jquery `css( propertyName , value  )` api but according to me the easier way because if there is many style like you have set the font ,color ,height,...the second method is easier and lot more time saving

```
 $("div").css("color", "yellow")
```

2 you can do this  by `removeClass('someClass');` and `addClass('someClass');`

for example, use a jQuery selector to target the division element with the class "some"

html

```
<div class="some" ></div>
```

css

```
.some{ color: green; }
```

jquery

if you want to add another class can use the addClass

```
$(".some").click( function(){
   $(this).addClass('someClass');
});
```

If you would like to remove the class, use jQuery's removeClass method:

```
$(".some").click( function(){
   $(this).removeClass('someClass');
});
```

Comment: @ahren calm down, dude. OP edited less than 5 minutes ago... For all but the last point, you can edit/suggest edits to answers. You have the power to correct his answer.

Comment: @ahren op has edited the question after my answer and i didn't kno that otherwise i would have been make it correct

Comment: FYI, `.live()` is deprecated and `.on()` is preferred with the latest jQuery.